# Refresh data in AdvancedDataGrid, after data change (AS3)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I am using the `AdvancedDataGrid` control. In that I am showing the data in hierarchical format in that I have one parent with two children. In the parent I have a checkbox, and when I select the checkbox, I have to remove the existing data of children and replace with new ones.

Answer (score 2):

[I am assuming this question is for AS3]

Faced a similar problem, to refresh the advanceDataGrid, after you manipulated the source data just run

> advanceDataGrid.invalidateList();

It will then refresh on the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the data when displaying hierarchical data simply refresh the group list in the advanced datagrid.

The API is not consistent which trips many ppl up.

groupList.refresh();

```
<mx:dataProvider>
   <mx:GroupingCollection id="groupList" source="{OrderDB.flatData}" >
     <mx:Grouping>
        <mx:GroupingField name="benchmark" >
         <mx:summaries>
```